# Matricial equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Find the matrix $x$ that satisfies:

$(a^Tx-3bx)c^T = b^4 + 5xc^T$
a, b and c are matrices with same dimensions.

What I did was use the distributive property and multiply by inverse.

$(a^Tx-3bx)c^T - 5xc^T= b^4 $

$(a^Tx-3bx)c^T - 5xc^T= b^4 $

$[(a^Tx-3bx) - 5x]c^T= b^4 $

$a^Tx-3bx - 5x= b^4 (c^T)^{-1} $

$(a^T-3b - 5)x= b^4 (c^T)^{-1} $

$x= (a^T-3b - 5)^{-1}b^4 (c^T)^{-1} $

Using the values for the matrices I was given I checked if it was right in Wolfram but it's not. Maybe transpose matrices have a property I don't know.
$a^T$ means transpose of $a$ by the way.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes here so far. What are the values you used for the matrices anyways?

Comment: The $5$ in the last couple of lines is not a matrix, you must mean $5 \cdot I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: no, it's a scalar.

Comment: a = {{1, 0, 1, 2 }, {-2, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 4, 1, 0}, {3, -2, 1, -1}}
                                                                                                                    
b = {{2, -3, 2, 2}, {-7, -1, -2, 0}, {1, 2, 1, -1}, {-2, 3, 1, -1}}
                                                                                                                
c = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, -1, 0}, {3, 0, 1, -5}}

Comment: @bajotupie You wrote $a^T-3b-5$ but you can't add a scalar to a matrix. What you need is $5 \cdot I$ there. Note that Wolfram Alpha will allow you to enter a sum between a matrix and a scalar, but will add the scalar to *each* element of the matrix, which gives the wrong result for what you have here.

Comment: It worked thanks :D